# GStreamer OMX plugins on Ubuntu, x86 machine

Tags: gstreamer

Can I install and use the OMX plugins on my Linux box running on x86? I can't find it using gst-inspect-1.0 and I can't use it in my pipelines either.

Answer (score 2):

So have you installed it or not? what distribution of Linux?

I havent found any ppa repository or anything so I guess you have to compile it (there is some repo for raspbian but I guess you arent doing this for raspberry?).

Maybe you have to compile whole gstreamer or maybe just this package if you already have some gstreamer plugins installed (you have to try, I dont know)

You can compile it from [source](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-omx/) like:

```
git clone https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-omx/
./autogen.sh && make && make install
```

But you have to have other dependancies - that is at least gstreamer, gst-plugins-base ..

There are some infos [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/how-can-i-install-gstreamer-gst-omx) - its for raspberry but it may work for you.

try, hack it a little and write back

UPDATE:

Ok I found this info [here](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/GstOpenMAX/#howtotryit):

> How to try it It depends on your platform, but if want to try on x86
>   you can use Bellagio's implementation:
>
> So, first install Bellagio's omxil from
>   [here](http://omxil.sourceforge.net/) ....

Comment: Well, I use Ubuntu 14.04. It appears that these OMX plugins are available only for low-power embedded devices... I am not doing it for raspberry, this is an x86 machine. My real question I guess is, these OMX plugins take advantage of the OpenMax API right? Who provides this OpenMax API? Can I take advantage of a custom DSP's hardware using these plugins?

Comment: I dont know which dependancies you must have for openmax.. so I guess you could not built it from source .. you have to have some special HW for this? I am afraid I cannot help you much more here.. maybe try asking on IRC (at freenode channel #gstreamer) they are nice there :)

Comment: Thanks will look into it!

Comment: otopolsky  @nirvanaswap : Correct, on PC you can get the OMX API from Bellagio. But this is just an sample to understand OMX. Unless you want to understand OMX, it is useless to use gst-omx on PC. Just use other plugins such as gst-libav instead. gst-omx is used on embedded device because the manufacture may provide OMX library for their hardware (as in case of Raspberry Pi)